# SeriLog not outputing non-string data

Tags: serilog

I'm just getting started with SeriLog in a Core 2 web app and have pasted sample code into my controller:

```
    _logger.LogInformation("Before");

    using (_logger.BeginScope("Some name"))
    using (_logger.BeginScope(42))
    using (_logger.BeginScope("Formatted {WithValue}", 12345))
    using (_logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["ViaDictionary"] = 100 }))
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Hello from the Index!");
        _logger.LogDebug("Hello is done");
    }

    _logger.LogInformation("After");
```

but the output excludes the lines that are not flat text:

```
2017-11-01 14:53:19.587 -05:00 [Information] Before
2017-11-01 14:53:19.588 -05:00 [Information] Hello from the Index!
2017-11-01 14:53:19.588 -05:00 [Debug] Hello is done
2017-11-01 14:53:19.588 -05:00 [Information] After
```

On one hand that kinda makes sense but on the other - why include it in the repos sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeginScope` adds the metadata to Scope object associated with contained messages.

You have to modify the `outputTemplate` to see the passed values, as per [discussion in SeriLog's issues list](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/issues/65):

```
.WriteTo.LiterateConsole(outputTemplate:
    "{Timestamp:o} [{Level:u3}] {Scope} {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
```

Also, note the remarks on [how Scope is affected by the values passed to `BeginScope`](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/11/ilogger-beginscope/)

> Just because you can pass practically anything to BeginScope() doesn’t mean that you necessarily should. It’s important for a provider to capture the most useful information it can, hence this article, but as a diagnostic aid I’m strongly biased towards the judicious use of Dictionary scope values, rather than hierarchical scope names.
>
> Structured key/value properties are self-documenting and simpler to query. A log filter like OrderId = 54 is easy to formulate. The Scope array doesn’t attach any meaning to each level in the hierarchy: Scope[?] = 'Downloading messages' might retrieve a meaningful set of events, but Scope[0] = 42 is just nonsense.
>
> Of course, the flexibility is there, so you should use the API in the manner that makes the most sense to you :-).

Comment: Another option to consider, instead of `{Scope}`, is to include `{Properties}` in the output template. This will print `Scope`, when it exists, but also the other key-value properties suggested in the quoted paragraph. Cheers! :-)